# Does $\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-t\sin t}\;dt$ converge?

Tags: improper-integrals

> Does $I=\displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-t\sin t}\;dt$ converge?

I haven't got the correction so, I would like to know if it's correct.

---

$\forall t\in \big[(2k+1)\pi,\; (2k+2)\pi\big],\quad  t\sin t\ \le 0\implies e^{-t\sin t}\ge 1$

Then $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n\int_{(2k+1)\pi}^{(2k+2)\pi}e^{-t\sin t}\;dt\ge \sum_{k=0}^n\int_{(2k+1)\pi}^{(2k+2)\pi}1\;dt=(n+1)\pi$

since $(n+1)\pi\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty\implies I$ diverges

Comment: Since you tagged the question with [tag:improper-integrals], the context is probably improper Riemann integrals, not Lebesgue integrals?

Comment: Yes I haven't studied yet, the Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: For completeness you should point out that the integrand is nonnegative, so $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t \sin t}\ dt$ is at least as large as your sum. Aside from that, your argument is fine.

Comment: I wanted to write that first, but as it's obvious that for any $t\in\mathbb{R}, \quad e^t>0$. I haven't done it.

Comment: You should have, since for $f(t) = \frac{\sin t}{t}$ the observation that $$\sum_{k = 0}^n \int_{2k\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi} f(t)\,dt \geqslant \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{(2k+1)\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin t\,dt = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{2k+1} > \frac{1}{\pi}\log n \to +\infty$$ doesn't imply the divergence of the integral. Your argument shows that for $\varepsilon < \pi$, there is no $K$ such that for $K \leqslant x < y$ the bound $$\Biggl\lvert\int_x^y f(t)\,dt\Biggr\rvert <\varepsilon$$ holds, hence the integral doesn't converge, but you don't explicitly say that either. Partial marks, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer  Do you mean, my proof is not sufficient???

Comment: That depends on what the purpose of the proof is. If it is to show fellow mathematicians that the integral doesn't converge, it would be sufficient for that purpose since the readers can fill in the gap on their own. But in an exercise, the purpose is to give a complete argument, and then it matters to state the obvious little things that you use in your argument, like $e^x > 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said

$$I_k=\int_{(2k+1)\pi}^{(2k+2)\pi}e^{-t\sin (t)}dt\ge 1$$

$$\implies \lim_{k\to+\infty}I_k\ne 0$$

thus, by Cauchy criterion, the integrale diverges.

Comment: Understood!! $$\exists A>0,\; \forall c \in (a,+\infty),\; \exists x,y\in (c,+\infty) \quad I_{[x,y]}>A$$

Comment: @Stu Tu prends $A=1/2$ par exemple.

Comment: Merci je n'avais pas pensé au critère de Cauchy. Bonne soirée

Comment: It is a very good question (+1).

Comment: @Fatima I'm looking for exercises about this topics, "improper integrale" and other exercises about big O and little o. If you have something to advice me I would be happy!!(books or anything else.

Comment: @Stu Malheureusement, pour le moment , à part les livres (cours +exercices) de Walter Rudin, je n'ai rien mais dès que j'aurais un bon lien,  je te le transmettrai.